# Azure swap not working

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I am trying to use **Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot** as it follows:

Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name 'sitename' -slot1 'Staging' -slot2 'Production' -f
orce -verbose


However even though my website has 2 slots, Staging and the default Production I still receive the following error from Power Shell.

```
Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot : The website must have at least two slots to apply swap
At line:1 char:1
+ Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name 'sitename' -slot1 'St ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.SwitchAzureWebsiteSlotCommand
```

Do you have any ideas why? Did you also encounter this during your code journeys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot** is for ASM websites. In your case, I think you have created an ARM website, hence **Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot** is not suitable here.

To swap slot for ARM websites, you need to use below script:

```
$ParametersObject = @{targetSlot  = "[slot name – e.g. “production”]"}
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName [resource group name]-ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName [web app name]/[slot name] -Action slotsswap -Parameters $ParametersObject -ApiVersion 2015-07-01
```

You can check [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) for details.

## Update:

**Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot** also works for ARM web app. My problem is that I have two subscriptions, I didn't select the correct subscription when testing the command previously. Thanks to Flemin!

Before:
[image]

Now with the right subscription:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This command works even if you have created app in ARM.

```
Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name 'siteName' -slot1 'StagingDeploymentName' -slot2 'Production' -force -verbose
```

Please check the names that you have given and if the slots are up and running.

I tested this by stopping one of the deployment slots and go the same error as you got. So, I'm sure now that in your case either one slot is not in running state.

Comment: @FleminAdambukulam yes, it got solved. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

For an ARM web app, `Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot` does not work for me at all. Get the following error message:

> Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot : No default subscription has been designated.
>   Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the
>   default subscription.

From what I understand, `Select-AzureSubscription` is an ASM command so it's not applicable. (Instead, for ARM I need to use `Select-AzureRmSubscription`.)

The command [`Swap-AzureRmWebAppSlot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt767927.aspx) is what worked for me:

```
Swap-AzureRmWebAppSlot -Name "sitename" -SourceSlotName "Staging" -DestinationSlotName "Production" -ResourceGroupName "<Your Resource Group Name"
```

Comment: I scratched my head for an hour whilst getting the same error message from our build server and after applying Ray's advice here on our build server release step it worked first time. Thanks Ray.